# Progress indicator when using a for loop to parse txt file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to create a really simple script that tests dns servers and returns the results into a csv file, and it works perfectly, but takes a long time with a large source file of domains.

Is there some way to use pv or awk to create a progress indicator?

```
#!/bin/bash
# File name of domain list: One FQDN per line in file.
domain_list='domains.txt'
#
# IP address of the nameserver used for lookups:
ns1_ip='1.1.1.1' # Cloudflare
ns2_ip='9.9.9.9' # Quad9
#
# Seconds to wait between lookups:
loop_wait='1'
#
echo "Domain name, $ns1_ip,$ns2_ip" > dns-test-results.csv;
for domain in `cat $domain_list`
do
    ip1=`dig @$ns1_ip +short $domain |tail -n1`; 
    ip2=`dig @$ns2_ip +short $domain |tail -n1`;
    echo -en "$domain,$ip1,$ip2\n" >> dns-test-results.csv;
# 
done;
```

Comment: Check the length of the input, keep a counter how many iterations you completed, print something like `3/20` in CLI (use `\r` to overwrite)

Comment: Code for progress indicators and spinners in Bash:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/238073/1412534

Answer (score 9):

You could store the items in an array first to count them, and then just print the number of processed items and the total on each loop iteration.

E.g. something like this:

```
items=( $(cat items.txt) )
i=0; for x in "${items[@]}"; do
    printf "\r%d/%d" "$(( i += 1 ))" "${#items[@]}";
    sleep 1  # do some actual work here
done
echo
```

Though note that relying on word-splitting of `$(cat file...)` is somewhat problematic, and you might be better off just using `readarray` to read each input file into an array element more safely:

```
readarray -t items < items.txt
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `readarray` unless this is a once-off script with known small input. If your file has millions of lines, this will hog memory unnecessarily, and while computers have lots of RAM these days, small VPSs generally don't.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, I don't think `readarray` is the issue there any more than any other way of reading the file to an array. You have to read the input one way or another anyway to count the lines if you want the progress indicator to show the total number of lines/items. (And in any case, the Q had `for x in $(cat file)`, which also reads into memory first.) Of course you could count the lines with `wc -l` first, and then read it again to process the data, which would save memory at the cost of twice the IO.

Comment: Unnecessary use of cat: items=( $(<items.txt) ) works just as well, ignoring all other issues.

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to what ilkkachu suggested, you can just read with a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File name of domain list: One FQDN per line in file.
domain_list='domains.txt'
number=$( wc -l < "$domain_list")
#
# IP address of the nameserver used for lookups:
ns1_ip='1.1.1.1' # Cloudflare
ns2_ip='9.9.9.9' # Quad9
#
# Seconds to wait between lookups:
loop_wait='1'
#
echo "Domain name, $ns1_ip,$ns2_ip" > dns-test-results.csv;
count=0
while read -r domain
do
  (( count++ ))
  printf '\rProcessing domain %d of %d' "$count" "$number"
  ip1=$(dig @$ns1_ip +short $domain |tail -n1); 
  ip2=$(dig @$ns2_ip +short $domain |tail -n1);
  printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "$domain" "$ip1" "$ip2" >> dns-test-results.csv;
  sleep "$loop_wait"
# 
done < "$domain_list"
echo
```

The code above will print `Processing domain x of y` where `x` is the current number being looked at and `y` the total number of lines in `$domains_list`.

Comment: If you put the `\r` at the beginning of the `printf` string you can leave the cursor hovering while the lookup's happening. You can also drop a quick `tput el` (or `el=$(tput el)` and use `"$el"`) at the end of the `printf` string so that shorter domain names don't show detritus left by earlier longer names

Comment: @ChrisDavies I don't really see why having the cursor at the start is better, what a I missing here? The `tput` makes sense, but seems like overkill since we're only showing numbers. Granted, if we have thousands, that can be a problem but I would fix that by using something like ` printf 'Processing domain %7s of %7s\r' "$count" "$number"`.

Comment: The `\r` at the front would leave the cursor at the end of the text. And re `tput el` I misread `domain %d` as `domain %s`

Comment: Ah yes, I see. That is indeed neater, thanks, fixed.

Comment: This looks like a nice and easy solution to me. Thank you!

Even though I have the `\r' my cursor is still on the far left on the P in Processing.

Comment: @0zero7 yes, if you want it to be on the right, remove the `\r` from the beginning and add it to the end: `printf 'Processing domain %d of %d\r' "$count" "$number"`.

Comment: Also, @0zero7 If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites. Please don't feel any pressure to accept mine, accept whichever one you end up using.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `printf .` to your script each time a record has been checked. And pipe through pv like (assuming `domains.txt` is line separated per record):

```
script.sh | pv -p -s "$(wc -l < domains.txt)" > /dev/null
```

But you can make even nicer.

Instead of `echo -en "$domain,$ip1,$ip2\n" >> dns-test-results.csv;`, you can just have `echo "$domain,$ip1,$ip2"`. Then use the `pv` line mode and invoke in a more "separation of concerns" manner:

```
script.sh | pv -p -l -s "$(wc -l < domains.txt)" > dns-test-results.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cause the shell to print progress info at regular intervals using traps.

```
#!/bin/bash

# child sends SIGUSR1 to the parent every $PERIOD seconds.

MAINPID=$BASHPID
PERIOD=3

pinger()  {
    (
    trap exit ERR
    while true
    do
        sleep $PERIOD
        kill -USR1 $MAINPID
    done
    ) &
}

# ====

# when main process receives SIGUSR1, print some progress info

trap progress SIGUSR1

progress() {
    printf "Progress: %d spins are spun\r" $COUNT
    return
}

# ====

# Start the pinger
pinger

# actual work goes here

for((COUNT=1; COUNT<300; COUNT++))
do
    sleep 0.100
done

exit
```